# Use component within component within slot... don't know how else to word it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm using a slider component called **Hooper**. Everything works great, obviously I ave created a seperate component for this as I don't want to include it in my global app as I don't always use this.

```
<template>
    <hooper :infiniteScroll="true">
        <slide v-for="(image, index) in images" :style=" { backgroundImage: 'url(\'img/' + image + '\')' }" :key="index">dsadasd</slide>
    </hooper>
</template>

<script>

    import { Hooper, Slide } from 'hooper';
    import 'hooper/dist/hooper.css';

    export default {
        props: [
            'images'
        ],
        name: 'Hooper',
        components: {
            'hooper': Hooper,
            'slide': Slide
        }
    };
</script>
```

So to use this component I add it to my blade file as follows:

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <carousel :images="[ 'slider-1.jpg', 'slider-2.jpg', 'slider-3.jpg' ]" class="carousel"></carousel>

    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="p-4 text-lg font-sans">Home</h1>
    </div>

@endsection
```

## My Issue

So, I want to have the ability to add any HTML I want to each slide, and also define the image name, so in an ideal world I would have the following within my blade file:

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <carousel class="carousel">
        <slide :style=" { backgroundImage: 'url(\'img/image-1.jpg\')' }">
            <h3>header text</h3>        
            <p>dsadasfhshshsgfgas</p>
        </slide>
        <slide :style=" { backgroundImage: 'url(\'img/image-2.jpg\')' }">
            <h3>header text 2</h3>        
            <p>dsadasdsdsadsafhshshsgfgas</p>
        </slide>
    </carousel>

    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="p-4 text-lg font-sans">Home</h1>
    </div>

@endsection
```

However **slide** is not a registered component, how would I do this?

---

## Had another idea for this.

Thought I could create a slot for each loop within my component, and then over-ride that slot within the blade file, like so:

`Carousel.vue`

```
<template>
    <hooper :infiniteScroll="true" class="carousel">
        <slide v-for="(image, index) in images" :style=" { backgroundImage: 'url(\'img/' + image + '\')' }" :key="index">
            <slot :name="'slide' + index"></slot>
        </slide>
    </hooper>
</template>

<script>

    import { Hooper, Slide } from 'hooper';
    import 'hooper/dist/hooper.css';

    export default {
        props: [
            'images'
        ],
        name: 'Hooper',
        components: {
            'hooper': Hooper,
            'slide': Slide
        }
    };
</script>
```

`home.blade.php`

```
<carousel :images="[ 'slider-1.jpg', 'slider-2.jpg', 'slider-3.jpg' ]" class="carousel">
    <template v-slot="slide1">
        <h2>dsdasdadas</h2>
        <p>dsdadasdasds</p>
    </template>
</carousel>
```

This doesn't appear to be working and i'm unsure why, anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last example with dynamic slot names should work, except it uses v-slot wrong. Your intended use is probably

```
<carousel :images="[ 'slider-1.jpg', 'slider-2.jpg', 'slider-3.jpg' ]" class="carousel">
  <template #slide1="slotProps">    // slotProps are optional here, if you want to pass data from Hooper/Slide to the slot
    <h2> Header </h2>
    <p> Text </p>
  </template> 
  <template #slide2>
    <h3> Different Header </h3>
    <div> Different Text </div>
  </template>
</carousel>
```

v-slot="slide1" is equivalent to v-slot:default="slide1", e.g. you're assigning the props received by the default slot (not available) to the name slide1.